# Re-Inserting deleted rows into the same table SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, triggers, insert

After searching many pages I still can't find the answer about re-inserting deleted rows in the same table - not another table.

I have a table named timetable with the primary key made up from 3 columns `Schoolcode, Year, Term`.

I need for some reason need to insert deleted rows into the same table.

I get the error

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint

with the following trigger

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[AFTER_delete_]
ON [dbo].timetable 
AFTER delete
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO timetable
            SELECT * 
            FROM deleted A 
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1  FROM timetable B      
                              WHERE B.Schoolcode = A.Schoolcode  
                                AND B.Year = A.Year   
                                AND B.Term = A.Term);
    END
END
```

Comment: SQL Server **2008** and **2008 R2** reached end of life well over a year ago and are now **completely unsupported** - and SQL Server **2005** even a few more years ...... You should **REALLY** be looking at upgrading to a supported version.

Comment: you need to provide table structure

Comment: This sounds like a terrible idea, but I know it is never easy to change your path. First, I suggest you simply throw an error if a row is deleted that **must exist and should never be deleted**. Alternatively, use an instead-of trigger to "filter" the deletions so that those "required" rows are not actually deleted.

Comment: @SMor  can you rewrite my code with instead- of trigger

Comment: Perhaps - but this is not a free code-writing service nor have you fully explained the rules for what can and what can not be deleted. It seems to me that your goal is simply to NOT allow any deletions. If so, we do that by setting the appropriate permissions. Alternatively, you simply throw an error in the delete trigger if any rows were affected by the deletion. I cannot see why you need any conditional logic here beyond verifying that rows exist in the deleted table.

Answer (score 0):

thanks any way.I test the code below and that did work.

```
    ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Instead_OfDelSert_Status]
    ON  [dbo].[Status]
    INSTEAD OF delete,insert
    AS
    BEGIN
    PRINT 'You must disable or delete Trigger  Instead_OfDelSert_Status  to insert or 
    delete rows!'
    END
```